# How does this line of code reap it's child processes?

Tags: c, linux, process

I have to analyse a small piece of code, and totally don't uderstand how does this line of code reap it's children processes:

```
while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
alarm(60);
```

I understand that the loop predicate will be always 1 while there are children that exists. But how does that reap, for instance, zombie processes?

Comment: It performs a system call, and by that system call the kernel will know that the parent knows the status of the zombie child. And thus the kernel knows can finally get rid of it.

Comment: That actually is how you reap a zombie. The definition of a zombie is a process that has exited but has not been reaped by its parent with `wait()` or `waitpid()`.

Comment: The code _won't_ reap [all] its child processes (because it uses `WNOHANG`). From the man page for `waitpid`, we have: _WNOHANG return immediately if no child has **exited**._ So, if there are still _running_ children, the function will return 0. And, the loop will terminate prematurely (with some still running children). Better to do: `while (waitpid(-1, NULL, 0) > 0);` Using `WNOHANG` might be okay if there is a [not shown] outer loop around this code. And, I think that the `alarm(60);` should be above the `while` if you want to continue if the children are not reaped with 60 secs.